# How to handle make missing from alpine docker image?

Tags: docker, go, makefile, command-line, dockerfile

i have Makefiles on my app , and all my commands on Makefile 
i put this on Dockerfile:

```
# start from the latest golang base image
FROM golang:alpine


RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache gcc && apk add --no-cache libc-dev

# Set the current working Directory inside the container
WORKDIR /app

# Copy go mod and sum files
COPY go.mod go.sum ./

# Download all dependencies. they will be cached of the go.mod and go.sum files are not changed
RUN go mod download

# Copy the source from the current directory to the WORKDIR inisde the container
COPY . .

# Build the Go app
RUN go build .

# Exporse port 3000 or 8000 to the outisde world
EXPOSE 3000

# Command to run the executable
CMD ["make", "-C", "scripts", "test" ]
CMD ["make", "-C", "scripts", "prod" ]
```

and got

```
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: 
        container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec: 
        \"make\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown.
```

is it possible to run `make -c scripts test` in Docker? how to correct way to use this command in Docker?

in `dockerfile` i run `golang:alpine`

Comment: Probably you don't have the `make` utility installed in your docker image.  If you want to run make _inside_ your container, you have to install the `make` program in your image.

Comment: does u know how to install it in alphine?

Comment: Does adding `apk add --no-cache make` to your Dockerfile help?

Comment: yes, it was work, I have a huge size image on docker when i add packages on alpine, should I just install those essentials package on main Linux? than install it with `apk`

Comment: Use a [multi-stage](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/) docker build. It's specifically designed for using a "bloated" development image for building/compile - and then the final stage can consist of just these artifacts (without all the tooling "bloat").

Answer (score 1):

here is two things I would fix in Dockerfile:

- add `apk add make`
- The CMD instruction is modified to use a shell form to chain the
  execution of your make commands. If these commands are meant to be
  alternatives or options, consider using an entrypoint script or
  another mechanism to select between them rather than trying to
  execute both sequentially.

```
    # Start from the latest golang base image
    FROM golang:alpine
    
    # Install system dependencies including 'make'
    RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache gcc libc-dev make
    
    # Set the current working Directory inside the container
    WORKDIR /app
    
    # Copy go mod and sum files
    COPY go.mod go.sum ./
    
    # Download all dependencies. They will be cached if the go.mod and go.sum files are not changed
    RUN go mod download
    
    # Copy the source from the current directory to the WORKDIR inside the container
    COPY . .
    
    # Build the Go app
    RUN go build .
    
    # Expose port 3000 to the outside world
    EXPOSE 3000
    
    # Use a single CMD instruction to run your make commands
    # If you have multiple make commands consider using a shell script or chaining commands
    CMD ["sh", "-c", "make -C scripts test && make -C scripts prod"]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you added `RUN apk add --no-cache make` and still there is an issue, add this as well to your DockerFile:

```
RUN apk add g++
```

Alpine images are lightweight and do not have utilities in them, adding g++ solves that. You can check the output by using the `which make` command, for me it returns `/usr/bin/make`

Ref: https://mroldan.medium.com/alpine-sh-make-not-found-1e87ab87c56

Answer (score -2):

if you wish to avoid adding all dependencies of make to your alpine image and keep the shipping container small in size:

- build your binary outside ur container and copy only the shippable binary to ur alpine container
- build your binary in a normal golang container then copy the binary to a small shippable alpine container
- you could give https://github.com/go-task/task a try, does not require too many dependencies compared to installing make in ur alpine container and replace ur make file with task file.